# Custom attached properties in Windows Runtime Components?

Tags: windows-runtime, win-universal-app, c++-cx, winrt-component

I'm trying to use the c# class library https://github.com/MacawNL/WinRT-RichTextBlock.Html2Xaml in a C++ UWP project. To my limited knowledge, I have to build the project as a Windows Runtime Component instead of a class library to use it with C++/cx. The problem is, when I try to build it as a winmd, I get this error:

```
Error   WME1024 Type 'WinRT_RichTextBlock.Html2Xaml.Properties' contains externally visible field 'Windows.UI.Xaml.DependencyProperty WinRT_RichTextBlock.Html2Xaml.Properties.HtmlProperty'.  Fields can be exposed only by structures.    WinRT-RichTextBlock.Html2Xaml   C:\Users\zzz\Downloads\WinRT-RichTextBlock.Html2Xaml\RichTextBlockProperties.cs 40
```

How do I build this attached property so I can use it in a c++/cx UWP project?

Comment: Use a read-only property instead of a field

Comment: Thanks for responding. I'm not sure of the implementation of a read-only property for a dependencyproperty. Can you provide a code example?

Comment: It's the same as a read only property for anything else.

Comment: Change *public* to *internal*.

Comment: @RaymondChen Thanks, that ended up working.